# How to use wget to download a file stored in Google Drive without making publicly shareable link of the specific file?

Tags: command-line, download, wget, google-drive

First make the file publicly shareable then:-
I use for small files download

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O FILENAME
```

for large files

```
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILEID" -O FILENAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

But how to do it without making publicly shareable link?

Note: wget is not a must for me.If you know any other software please recommend   me but it must contain following features:-

1. **Commandline based**
2. **Download file resume feature**
3. lightweight and portable (if possible , its not compulsory)
4. Multi-thread downloading and file appending feature(if possible , its not compulsory)

Comment: *'But how to do it without making a publicly shareable link?*" - I would be skeptical that this is even possible, both for technical as well as security related reasons. If you want to have direct access to files via e.g. `wget`, you are likely better off placing them on a normal web or ftp server, even ones you host yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at `rclone` https://rclone.org/

It's got a very complete feature set, is command-line based (syntax is very similar to `rsync`) and [supports Google Drive](https://rclone.org/drive/) via OAuth. Should be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

While many previous methods no longer work, I found that the following method still works (at least as for today):

```
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILE_ID" -O FILE_NAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

(replace FILE_ID and FILE_NAME with the file id from the google drive download link, and the name of the file you wish to download)

(answer originally found in https://silicondales.com/tutorials/g-suite/how-to-wget-files-from-google-drive/)

Answer (score 2):

Create a bash script called `getgoogle` somewhere in your PATH, e.g. /usr/local/bin or ~/bin (if you've mapped that in your environment)

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == *"id="* ]]; then
    ID=${1##*'id='}
else
    ID=$1
fi
echo "Retrieving Google drive item with ID $ID"
wget --no-check-certificate -r "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$ID" -O $(curl -s "https://drive.google.com/file/d/$ID/
view?usp=sharing" | grep -o '<title>.*</title>' | cut -d'>' -f2 | awk -F ' - Goo' '{print $1}')
```

make sure you change the permissions on the `getgoogle` script after saving it by running:

```
chmod u+x getgoogle
```

### Usage:

`getgoogle <URL|ID>`

Will download the Google Drive item whether you have the full link as `URL` or just the identifier `ID` and rename it upon download to the original filename of the file that was uploaded to Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked almost flawlessy. The only additional step I had to take is that, after a few tens of redirect, the script downloaded `410294` more bytes on the beginning of the binary I wanted (these `410294` bytes started with: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Google Drive - Virus scan warning</title>`) so I had to perform a `dd` with `skip` to remove this HTML header.